# covariance of lognormal random variables

Tags: distributions, variance, random-variable, standard-deviation, covariance

I am trying to find the variance of b*log(x+y) - log(x), where x and y are independent and identically distributed lognormal random variables, the range for log(x) and log(y) is negative infinity to infinity, and 0<b<1. I have used the Fenton-Wilkinson (FW) approximation to find the variance of log(x+y), but I also need to find the covariance(log(x+y), log(x)) since both terms have x in common. FW doesn’t seem to help me with this problem (although I may be wrong). I had assumed that covariance(log(x+y), log(x)) = variance(log(x)) but my simulations do not support this answer.

Comment: The fact that you need an approximation of $\log(X+Y)$ is revealing!  The sum of independent, nonsingular lognormal variables is never lognormal.  Although we might still hope to be able to compute moments, it doesn't look likely.  To what extent, then, would you be interested in approximations to the moments?  Over what ranges of parameters?

Comment: Thank you @whuber for your quick response! I actually need to find variance(log(x+y) - log(x)), where x, y are iid lognormal. I approximate x+y to be lognormal using Fenton-Wilkinson (FW). There must clearly be a covariance term because both terms have x in common. FW doesn't seem to help me with this case (I may be wrong) but I would be happy with any approximation. The range for log(x) and log(y) is negative infinity to infinity.

Comment: A slight simplification is that $\log(X+Y)-\log(X)=\log(1+Y/X)=\log(Z)$ where $Z=Y/X$ is lognormal because $(X,Y)$ is lognormal.  The range is not helpful: what matters are the values of the parameters of $Z.$ For instance, when $Z$ has a tiny geometric mean and tiny geometric SD, you can approximate $\log(1+Z)$ by $Z$ itself; and when $Z$ has a large GM and not too large GSD, $\log(Z)$ is a good approximation.

Comment: Thank you. I actually need to find the variance of beta*log(X+Y) - log(X), where 0<beta<1. I had simplified the problem when I stated it and you have made me realize that I over simplified it.

Comment: *Please* ask the question you actually face.  This makes it more likely the answers will be useful.

Comment: Yes; my apologies.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the new information.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment that is too long for the comment box, but might spur someone else to prove the result.

There appears to be a very clean exact solution, namely that, if $X \sim \text{LogNormal}(\mu,\sigma)$ is independent of $Y \sim  \text{LogNormal}(\mu,\sigma)$, then:

$$\text{Cov}[\log(X+Y), \log(X)] = \frac12  \sigma^2$$

The proof, like Ramanujan, is ...

Comment: +1 This is why I have repeatedly asked the OP to state their assumptions about the parameters: the *iid* case appears much more tractable.  (So is the more general case where the geometric means differ but the geometric SDs are the same.)  Some things can be inferred from general principles: in the *iid* case, the formula must be a function of $\sigma^2$ alone, for instance.

Comment: Thank you @wolfies!!!!! This is indeed beautifully clean and agrees with my simulations. Would you please share your intuition?

Comment: Thank you @whuber. That is a helpful insight and I appreciate your help with my problem (which has been halting progress on my research).